# I changed my url and cant access my site, Help?

Tags: urls

I tried to change my URL and ended up losing access to my site?

I went into general settings and changed both WordPress URL and Site URL to my new URL. I have my site running again but still have no idea how to set up my new domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you were attempting a site migration you should have backed up all your files and database tables before changing your URL. When you change your site URL (presumably from the Settings->General option page), you are essentially modifying every link on the site to point to the new URL. If that URL is not setup with WordPress on it, then your site will crash wonderfully.

Fortunately, nothing is too permanent in WordPress. If you have access to your database, you'll want to get in there and revert your website settings back to your existing (and working) URL. The table that holds these entries is the "wp_options" table and it most likely will be the first two entries in there with option names of "siteurl" and "home" that will have your newest/ latest changes to your URL.

Comment: Ok, So I ended up restoring everything via the files i backed up before I changed the URL. I also can't find the wp-option.php. I have a optiom.php but no mention of the site URL. So how do I actually change the domain without messing everything up. currently I can type in my purchased godaddy domain and the site pops up but I can't access that dash board using that method.

Comment: You don't want to touch the files, especially core files inside of the WordPress structure. the "wp-options" is a database table. Sounds like you used GoDaddy's automated installer so you probably didn't have to get your hands dirty until now with the database. You should have in your GoDaddy account somewhere access to a database that is housing your WordPress information. If you can find that and open up PHPMyAdmin to view your database files then you should be able to find the "wp-options" table.

Comment: I host on my own server and installed it myself. I bought the domain using godaddy then selected forward with masking.

Comment: ok I found the PHPMyAdmin file and the wp-options table.